# 2 Tables - one customer, one transactions. How to handle a customer with no transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables-one customers, one transactions.  One customer does not have any transactions.  How do I handle that?  As I'm trying to join my tables, the customer with no transaction does not show up as shown in code below.

```
SELECT Orders.Customer_Id, Customers.AcctOpenDate, Customers.CustomerFirstName, Customers.CustomerLastName, Orders.TxnDate, Orders.Amount
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.Customer_Id=Customers.Customer_Id;
```

I need to be able to account for the customer with no transaction such as querying for least transaction amount.

Comment: By transaction do you mean "order"? Either start with the customer table and left join on the orders. Or union all the customers with no orders.

Comment: used right outer join in this case.

Comment: yes, I'm using order instead of transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER Joins show only those records that are present in BOTH tables

OUTER joins gets SQL to list all the records present in the designated table and shows NULLs for the fields in the other table that are not present

LEFT OUTER JOIN (the first table)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (the second table)
FULL OUTER JOIN (all records for both tables)

Get up to speed on the join types and how to handle NULLS and that is 90% of writing SQL script.

Below is the same query with a left join and using ISNULL to turn the amount column into 0 if it has no records present

```
SELECT Orders.Customer_Id, Customers.AcctOpenDate, Customers.CustomerFirstName, Customers.CustomerLastName
, Orders.TxnDate, ISNULL(Orders.Amount,0)
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Orders.Customer_Id=Customers.Customer_Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below updated query -  Right Outer join is used instead of Inner join to show all customers regardless of the customer placed an order yet.

```
 SELECT Orders.Customer_Id, Customers.AcctOpenDate, 
 Customers.CustomerFirstName, Customers.CustomerLastName, 
 Orders.TxnDate, Orders.Amount
 FROM Orders
 Right Outer JOIN Customers ON Orders.Customer_Id=Customers.Customer_Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 SELECT Orders.Customer_Id, Customers.AcctOpenDate, Customers.CustomerFirstName, Customers.CustomerLastName, Orders.TxnDate, Orders.Amount
 FROM Orders
 Right OUTER JOIN Customers ON Orders.Customer_Id=Customers.Customer_Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend `LEFT JOIN`.  This keeps all rows in the first table, along with matching columns in the second.  If there are no matching rows, these columns are `NULL`:

```
SELECT c.Customer_Id, c.AcctOpenDate, c.CustomerFirstName, c.CustomerLastName,
       o.TxnDate, o.Amount
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.Customer_Id = c.Customer_Id;
```

Although you could use `RIGHT JOIN`, I never use `RIGHT JOIN`s, because I find them *much* harder to follow.  The logic of "keep all rows in the first table I read" is relatively simple.  The logic of "I don't know which rows I'm keeping until I read the last table" is harder to follow.

Also note that I included table aliases and change the `CustomerId` to come from `customers` -- the table where you are keeping all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using CASE will replace "null" with 0 then you can sum the values. This will count customers with no transactions.

```
SELECT c.Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as TransactionsPerCustomer
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Transactions t
    ON c.Name = t.customerID
group by c.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as numberoftransaction
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN transactions t
ON c.Name = t.customerID
group by c.Name